# How to create telerik RadTextbox dynamically from client side on button click

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Is there anyway to create RadTextbox dynamically from client side like the ordinary html textbox like this.

$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btnCreateTextBox1").click(function(){
                $("", {type: "text", "class": "numeric" }).appendTo('#container');
            });
         });
Here it is an client side control it is creating but what about for the server control like RadTextbox or asp.net textbox control.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a way to take a server control such as the RadTextBox and dynamically create it on the client. Taking a look at your specific example the reason this works is because, as you mentioned, you are creating a regular HTML element and not a complex control with potentially several HTML elements and server-side API.

You could of course instantiate the RadTextBox dynamically on the server-side or just use the markup approach for the non-dynamic way. You can then interact with the control via it's client-side objects as mentioned in [this documentation article](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-client-side-basics.html).